# Image created through html2canvas and uploaded to firebase storage has size of 0KB

Tags: javascript, firebase-storage, html2canvas

I am trying to create an image of a div using html2canvas and upload to firebase storage. Every bit of the code works fine apart from the fact that the uploaded image has 0 kb size. Looks like the canvas element is not converted ultimately to an image. Here is the div and next is the code to upload

```
<div id="refit" style="margin: 3%; border: solid; border-radius: 4px; border-width: 3px;">
    <p style="margin-right: 2%; margin-left: 2%; "><u>Complaint/Issues:</u></p>
</div>
```

The script to convert this to an image and upload is as follows, The variable filename has been defined:

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById("refit")).then(function(canvas) {
                        var screenshot = canvas.toDataURL();
                        var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
                        var imagesRef = storageRef.child('Images/'+filename+'.jpg');
                        imagesRef.putString(screenshot,'data_url',{contentType:'image/jpg'}).then((snapshot) => {
                            snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
                                firebase.database().ref('Somewhere/' + filename).update({ Something1: downloadURL, Something2: "Complete" },function(error){
                                    if (error) {
                                                alert("Network Error: Try again");
                                                
                                            } else {
                                                
                                                alert(" Submitted")
                                              
                                            }
                                })
                            })
                            
                        });
                    });
```

Comment: `and upload` have you confirmed, using the browser *developer* tools, that an upload actually takes place?

Comment: getDownloadURL is getting the link to the uploaded file to be stored in realtime database. I thought putString is uploading the file

Comment: yeah, I realised after I read the code again :p